# I can't update my settings on wamp server 3.2.0

Tags: php, wamp

I am using wamp 3.2.0 I have to change some settings in wamp like

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
max_input_vars = 10000
```

when I change values from wamp tray icon.wamp services restart and when i open php.ini file the changes that I made are there means file has been updated.But if I open wamp tray again it shows old values and  error on sending large data on get request presist. same is with uploading large files.
phpinfo also shows updated values.

Comment: First update to WAMPServer 3.2.8 [The backup repo is easier to navigate](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en)

Comment: Second, `post_max_size` should be larger than `upload_max_filesize` as first its possible to upload multiple files of 256M so all of them have to fit inside the `post_max_size` and Second, you need space for the ordinary fields in the form as well

Comment: If `phpinfo()` tells you the updated params then they are what is being used. Its probably a little bug with the wampmanager (the little icon on the system tray) I would upgrade if you can. There is also an upgrade to wampmanager

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243870/discussion-on-question-by-abbas-i-cant-update-my-settings-on-wamp-server-3-2-0).